# undefined method `will_save_change_to_address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, geocoding

I am new to coding and a friend and I are making a website that has a map with markers. For some reason it's working when she pulls the master branch but when I pull origin master on GitHub I get errors and no markers. Does anyone know why it works on one devise but not on another? We have been constantly running into this issue.

**product model**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
  has_one_attached :photo
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, if: :will_save_change_to_address?
  include PgSearch::Model
  pg_search_scope :search_by_name_and_category,
  against: [ :name, :category ],
  using: {
    tsearch: { prefix: true } # <-- now `superman batm` will return something!
  }
end
```

**product controller**

```
def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @products = Product.search_by_name_and_category(params[:query])
    else
      @products = Product.all
      @markers = @products.geocoded.map do |product|
        {
          lat: product.latitude,
          lng: product.longitude
        }
      end
    end
  end

private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :category, :price, :description, :address)
  end
```

**view**

```
<div class="card-product-container">
  <div class="cards">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="card-product">
        <%= link_to product_path(product.id) do %>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?<%= product.name %>" />
          <div class="card-product-footer">
            <div style="text-decoration:none;">
              <h2><%= product.name %></h2>
              <p>Owner <%= product.user.first_name %></p>
            </div>
          <h2><%= product.price %></h2>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

    <div style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"
      data-controller="map"
      data-map-markers-value="<%= @markers.to_json %>"
      data-map-api-key-value="<%= ENV['MAPBOX_API_KEY'] %>">
    </div>
</div>
```

**schema**

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "category"
    t.boolean "available"
    t.string "image"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "price"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id"
  end
```

**map controller**

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    apiKey: String,
    markers: Array
  }

  connect() {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = this.apiKeyValue

    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.element,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10"
    });
    this.#addMarkersToMap()
    this.#fitMapToMarkers()
  }

  #fitMapToMarkers() {
    const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds()
    this.markersValue.forEach(marker => bounds.extend([ marker.lng, marker.lat ]))
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 70, maxZoom: 15, duration: 0 })
  }

  #addMarkersToMap() {
    this.markersValue.forEach((marker) => {
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat([ marker.lng, marker.lat ])
        .addTo(this.map)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `will_save_change_to_address?` comes from the [Rails method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-will_save_change_to_attribute-3F) `will_save_change_to_attribute?` . You get an error, because your `Product` model is missing `address` attribute. Just create a migration adding this column to the `products` table.